# Visualizing css grid computed state as in inspectors

Tags: javascript, css, css-grid

I am creating a learning tool for the new display:grid css feature. 
I encountered the need to visualize the created grid in an inline way, which would be similar to the way the grid is visualized in chrome's inspection tools, but without using it.

I currently could not find a way to sample the location and size of the computed grids in a given state. A solution I have tried which worked partially was create a temporary div using:

```
 tempDiv = document.createElement("DIV");
 tempDiv.style.width = "100%";
 tempDiv.style.height = "100%";
 gridContainer.appendChild(tempDiv);
```

and then to measure each cell I have positioned like that (i.e for first row and first column):

```
 tempDiv.gridArea = "1 / 1 / 2 / 2"
```

and got the position and size using:

```
 templDiv.getBoundingClientRect()
```

It was looking promising until I got to realize that in many cases the adding of this temporary DIV will actually make changes to the grid layout.

Are there some js APIs to retrieve this infromation?
Can anyone think of a more clever way?

Comment: BTW, here's how Firefox does it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_grid_layouts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It was looking promising until I got to realize that in many cases the adding of this temporary DIV will actually make changes to the grid layout.

I think you can avoid that by setting `position: relative` on your `gridContainer`, and then absolutely positioning your div:

```
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```